# Running a WEBrick server on a shared harddrive Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, networking, webrick

I am on Windows 7, and at work we keep all of our project files on a shared "Z:" drive.

I used rails installer to get up and running on the networked drive, created a new test project and ran git / db:migrate and everything is fine.

Rails server boots up fine as well, but localhost:3000 in my browser can't find the instance (understandable).

Is there anything I can do?

UPDATE: I had tried to boot WEBrick from an IP Address (used to access local servers from other machines) but web brick gave me a "TCPServer Error: The requested address is not valid in its context."

SOLVED: I disabled web services via this post http://forums.iis.net/p/1150139/1872824.aspx and tried again at localhost:3000 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get up and running after disabling IIS and Web Publishing services in Windows 7. Instructions to do that here: http://forums.iis.net/p/1150139/1872824.aspx